# removeEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I don't know what I am doing wrong but here is an example of what I am doing and it doesn't seem to work.

```
someDom.addEventListener('mousemove',function(ev) {self.onInputMove(ev)},false);

someDom.removeEventListener('mousemove',self.onInputMove);
```

The removeEventListener code is executed but it just doesn't remove the 'mousemove' listener

Answer (score 27):

`removeEventListener` removes the listener that *exactly* matches the function that was added.

In this case, the function that `addEventListener` added was:

```
var some_func = function(ev) {
    self.onInputMove(ev);
};
```

Store a reference to the actual function and you'll be good.  So for example, the following should work:

```
someDom.addEventListener('mousemove',self.onInputMove,false);

someDom.removeEventListener('mousemove',self.onInputMove,false);
```

Comment: The third argument to removeEventListener is also mandatory so your exmple should be: `someDom.removeEventListener('mousemove', self.onInputMove, false);`

Comment: I know I'm several years late, but the third argument isn't actually mandatory right? I think it's supposed to be optional, and it should default to false.

Comment: It was once upon a time, but it is no longer mandatory.  I'll leave it in there just for clarity, but good point.

Comment: please explain about third parameter in `removeEventListener`? and I need to use `true` as third parameter in `addEventListener` so I could prevent default mouse clicks... (opening link), so I can't set `false` to this method..

Comment: If you use `true` for both `add` and `removeEventListener` it will work - the underlying issue is that the function which is added must be the exact same function as the function being removed.

Answer (score 6):

`onInputMove` is not an event-callback method. So you need to do something like:

```
var event = function(ev) {self.onInputMove(ev)};
someDom.addEventListener('mousemove', event,false);

someDom.removeEventListener('mousemove', event, false);
```

Comment: The third argument to removeEventListener is also mandatory so your exmple should be: `someDom.removeEventListener('mousemove', event, false);`

Comment: `event` isn't a good name for your eventhandler function reference

Answer (score 1):

Why make it yourself so hard, just use the following to bind an event to an element:

```
element.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // Some code here...
    alert("Mouse moved!");
};
```

Now, when you want to remove the event, just do this:

```
element.onmousemove = null;
```

Done!

Hope this helps you guys out!

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer. Good day to you kind sir. You just saved me.

Comment: @thandasoru not if you are using event listeners.

Comment: Because this uses the old event handlers as properties paradigm, rather than the DOM Level 2 event standard. And, because this technique doesn't allow for multiple handlers to a single event.

Comment: Also, it doesn’t allow you to specify capture or bubble, or other options.

Answer (score 1):

This page comes first on searching this/such issue on Google. So apart from answers already mentioned, here is one more interesting fact for future:

Leaving out the third optional variable in addEventListener() for useCapture/useBubble (as it defaults to false) does create some issue while removing the same eventlistener with same callback name. I faced this issue while working on chrome. Cant say about other browsers.

So do mention the third variable explicitly as "false".